# How to sort first M elements in N length array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have some tasks about sorting arrays in C#. I've been trying everything I could think of - no luck.

The task is to sort an array of integers by known sorting algorithms (insertion, selection, bubble, quick). Thing is, I have to sort **ONLY** the smallest `M` elements.

Example: I have an array of 7 elements `2 9 8 3 4 15 11` and I need to sort the smallest 3 elements so that my array becomes `2 3 4 9 8 15 11`.

Please help, I can't seem to find anything neither here in SO, nor anywhere through Google. I don't ask to do all the algorithms for me, I just need one of those just to get hold on how's that possible.

E: Thank you for your thoughts. I've reviewed all of your recommendations and have accomplished to make an insertion sort like that:

```
static int[] insertSort(int[] arr, out int swaps, out int checks) {
    int step = 0;
    swaps = 0;
    checks = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
        int min = arr[i], minind = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++) {
            checks++;
            if (arr[j] < min) {
                min = arr[j];
                minind = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = arr[minind];
        if (step < M) {
            for (int j = minind; j > i; j--) {
                swaps++;
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            }
            arr[i] = temp;
            swaps++;
            step++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Swaps and checks - requirement for my application.

P.S. I've seen many times that SO doesn't like to *do homework* for someone. That's why I haven't asked for code, I've just asked for thoughts on how to accomplish that.

Thanks again for those who have helped me out here.

Comment: Why is this so difficult? You just pretend the array is shorter than it actually is and sort it.

Comment: @Earlz Read the question again …

Comment: I'm 95% certain that the entire reason your teacher is having you only sort the first few items is specifically so that you can't just use existing solutions that you can find online.  (At least not without modifying them enough to demonstrate that you have some idea how they work.)

Comment: Is there any limitations on efficiency?  A naive approach would be quite simple.

Comment: @KDiTraglia `by known sorting algorithms (insertion, selection, bubble, quick)`  It's a way of forcing him to implement each of those and just stop part way, thus preventing him from copy/pasting existing solutions for those algorithms.

Comment: Yes, this is homework.
No limitations on efficiency.

Comment: @YOhan If you're implementing the solutions from scratch the added constraint is quite easy (with the algorithms mentioned; doing it with, for example, mergesort, would be rather hard).

Comment: How would sorting the first 3 elements in `2 9 8 3 4 15 11` become `2 3 4 9 8 15 11` ?

Comment: @Magnus Do you know how insertion sort works?  You find the smallest item and move it to the front, then find the next smallest and move it to the next position, and so on until you're done.  Do that `M` times.  That's what he needs to do.  Then he needs to do it for the other algorithms listed.

Comment: @Servy That is selection sort you are describing.

Comment: @Magnus The question is badly written, what he means is probably that he should only sort up to the first **X** smallest numbers, ergo `2 3 4`, and not give a F*** about the rest (since that is the question making the most academic sense)

Comment: @flindeberg I never remember the difference between the two; it's a small change in either case.

Comment: @Servy I cant see how you would interpret that from the question: "How to sort first M elements in N length array"

Comment: @Magnus I wouldn't interpret that from the title, but the sample input/output makes it rather clear, as well as the rest of the context of the question.  I find there are lots of questions that are hard to answer if you don't look beyond the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no efficiency limitations:

1. Set i to 0.
2. Look for the minimum among the not sorted elements.
3. Insert it into the position i, shift the array.
4. Increment i.
5. Repeat M times.

Complexity is O(N * M).

Comment: That's insertion sort.  He named several sorting implementation he needs to use; this is one of them.

Comment: @Servy I also asked for just one of those algorithms just to understand how's that possible. I **do not** need explanation of every method :)

I'll try this now.

Comment: As a hint for bubble, on your first pass you can also scan for the lowest M elements, remember them in a list or array, and on any further scan, only perform a swap if at least one of the elements being swapped is in that list. This should just drop in to an implementation that knows it's done when no swaps were performed in a pass.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your implementation, this is hard to answer.  There are many ways to do this, and most are straight-forward.

Here are a few ideas though:

1. Create a "temporary" array that only holds the numbers to sort, sort it, then replace in original array (probably a sub-optimal solution)
2. Use a for loop that iterates the number of times you need (3 or whatever).  This is probably the best solution
3. Post your code here on SO and some naive person will probably give you a solution so you don't have to do your schoolwork yourself. (This is a lazy and unbecoming solution)

Answer (score 1):

I think here is what you are looking for, this is an example sorting of array ascending based on specific indixes.

```
        int startIndex=2;
        int endIndex=5;
        int[] elements=new int[7];
        elements[0]=2; 
        elements[1]=9;
        elements[2]=8;
        elements[3]=3;
        elements[4]=4;
        elements[5]=15;
        elements[6]=11;
        for (int a=startIndex-1;a<endIndex;a++){
            for(int b=startIndex-1;b<endIndex;b++){
                if (elements[a]<elements[b]){
                    int temp =elements[a];
                    elements[a]=elements[b];
                    elements[b]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int c=0;c<elements.Length;c++){
            Console.Write(elements[c]+",");
        }
```

Just change the "<" to ">" if you want to sort it desc.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to take a look at what sorting algorithm you're required to use. Say for example we're using one that uses a for loop. Most cases you'd see something like this

for(int i = 0; i < arrayName.length(); i++)
{}

In your case, just change the parameters of the for loop

for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{}

Where M is less than arrayName.length(); and is the number of positions from the beginning you would like to sort.

The rest of the array, untouched, should remain the same.

Comment: If you look at the example its not that the first N items of the source array are sorted, its that the first N items of the fully sorted array should be correctly sorted.

Comment: This doesn’t fulfil the requirement. OP wants to sort the M *smallest* elements of the array, not the M *first*.

Comment: @Chris & Konrad.  For insertion sort, bubble sort, and selection sort they're the same.  Each iteration of the loop moves one item to the front of the array.  This wouldn't quite work for quick sort though, it would be a somewhat different modification.  Obviously it won't work in the general case; it just *happens* to work for almost all of the cases the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things. Most sorting algorithms use array.length as the maximum range. 
Could you just use m there instead? ie

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
```

Also, you could use a temporary array of the first m characters, sort it, then reassign.

```
int[] temp; 
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    temp[i] = realArray[i]; 
}
//sort, then
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    realArray[i] = temp[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the full array and put it into the an other one.

Truncate the new array to only keep the smallest x elements.
Get the largest number from that array (in your example, 4).

Loop through the initial array and append all numbers that are higher.

---

Input: 2 9 8 3 4 15 11
Sort all: 2 3 4 8 9 11 15
Truncate: 2 3 4

Get highest value from this array (4)
Loop through original array and append

Is 2 higher than 4? no
Is 9 higher than 4? yes, append (we now have: 2 3 4 9)
Is 8 higher than 4? yes, append (we now have: 2 3 4 9 8)
Is 3 higher than 4? no
Is 4 higher than 4? no
Is 15 higher than 4? yes, append (we now have: 2 3 4 9 8 15)
Is 11 higher than 4? yes, append (we now have: 2 3 4 9 8 11)

*This is not the most efficient way and might cause problems if you have duplicate numbers

Answer (score -2):

Any prescriptions on using LINQ?

```
int a[] = new int[] {2, 9, 8, 3, 4, 15, 11}; 
const int M = 5;
a = a.Take(M).OrderBy(e => e).ToArray(); // EDIT: Added .ToArray()
```

Comment: That's got to be cheating heh

Comment: @Earlz, Yes it is, but so is using SO.  And thanks for the upvote, I just broke 9000.

Comment: Try executing this; it won't produce the desired output.

Comment: Apparently the OP wrote one thing in the question but wanted something completely different.

Comment: @Magnus - thanx for the support.  It was a light hearted answer.